# Angular cdk Drap and drop not working as expected during search functionality

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, drag-and-drop, angular7

I have Implemented angular drag and drop with search functionality, In normal flow, it's working fine. But when I search any record and try to drag and drop the index of the record is getting changed and instead of search term previous data which is present at that index in the data container that is getting dropped.

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 ext-form-heading ">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="avlQueryString" id="search" placeholder="Search to type
 </div>

    <div class="mapping-container">
            <div
              cdkDropList
              #to="cdkDropList"
              [cdkDropListData]="availableRoles"
              [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[from]"
              class="mapping-list"
              (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
              <div class="mapping-box" *ngFor="let item of availableRoles | 
           filterPipe: avlQueryString : 'roleName' : availableRoles" cdkDrag>
                <div class="mapping-inline">
                  <i  class="fa fa-angle-double-left mapping-select pull-left" (click)="addToList(item.id)" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  {{item.roleName}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Below is the ts code:

```
    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
          moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, 
   event.currentIndex);
        } else {
          transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                            event.container.data,
                            event.previousIndex,
                            event.currentIndex);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [cdkDragData]="item" to the html element that you have cdkDrag on.

In drop() function, get the previous item index with:
const previousIndex = event.previousContainer.data.findIndex(item => item === event.item.data);
So use it instead of event.previousIndex.